# Checking to see if a loop ran without a conditional break

Tags: java

I am currently having a programming assignment. In this assignment, I am given a random Ascii image. My job is to convert it into CSV format. For example:
ascii image:

```
3
  **
******
  ** *+
```

csv format:

```
3
2, ,2,*,2, 
6,*
2, ,2*,1, ,1,*,1,+
```

here is my code:

```
public static void imageToNumRep(File input, File output)
throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(input);
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(output);
    while(in.hasNextLine())
    {
        int count = 0;
        String text = in.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i <= text.length() -2; i++)
        {
            if (text.charAt(i) == text.charAt(i + 1))
            {
                count++;
            }
            if (text.charAt(i) != text.charAt(i + 1))
            {
                System.out.print(count+1+ "," + text.charAt(i)+ ", ");
                count = 0;
            }
        }
        int count2 = 0;
        for (int j = text.length()-1 ; j>0 ; j--)
        {

            if (text.charAt(j - 1) == text.charAt(j))
            {
                count2++;
            }
            if (text.charAt(j) != text.charAt(j - 1))
            {
                System.out.println(count2 + 1 + "," + text.charAt(j));
                count2 = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is I will go to through every single line in the image.
In each line, I'll go from the first character to the last character, or the other way. If the current character is the same as the next character, I'll have a counter to count that. When I reach the point that the current character is not the same as the next character, or the previous character, I will print out the count and the character, indicating how many of that character I just run through, and I reset the count.

The problem is that this code only works in lines that have different characters. When I go through a line that has the same character from the beginning to the end, I cannot print that line, because I need a different character in that line in order to print. Any ideas?

Comment: You should make your title expose the actual issue, rather than saying it's an assignment. And what do you mean with "needing a different character in a line in order to print"?

Comment: So for example I have an ascii image that one of its line is like this: +++++++. what I am trying to do is to print out the csv format of it, in this case it is 7,+. But my code only works if there is a different character in that line. For example an ascii image: +++*. I will go through the character until i reach the *. When i reach the last +, I can print out 3,+

Answer (score 0):

The general structure of your loops, pseudo-code, is something like this (I'll use `else`, but it's the same idea as your example code):

```
for every character in string {
    if some condition is true {
        ...
    } else {
        output "the condition is false";
        break;
    }
}
```

The problem that you are having is that you'd like to take some action (e.g. print you string) if some condition is true for every character in the string (e.g. all the characters are the same). Of course, you can't know that until after you have gone through the loop. The typical approach is to find some way to make that information available outside the loop. Consider this, for example:

```
boolean atLeastOneFalse = false; // we'll use this flag...

for every character in string {
    if some condition is true {
        ...
    } else {
        output "the condition is false";
        atLeastOneFalse = true; // ...to track if our condition is false...
        break;
    }
}

if (!atLeastOneFalse) { // ... so we can tell if it was ever false or not when we're done checking.
    output "the condition was always true!";
}
```

Here we use a flag to keep track of what happened in the loop outside of the loop. If condition was true for every iteration through the loop, our flag will never be touched and will remain `false` after the loop. But if the condition was false, our flag is set.

The above approach is pretty clean and easy to read. A second approach along the same lines (getting information available out of the loop) is to declare your index counter outside the loop, then examine it's value at the end. For example:

```
int n;

for (n = 0; n < final value; ++ n) {
    if some condition is true {
        ...
    } else {
        output "the condition is false";
        break;
    }
}

if (n == final value) { // then we never broke out of the loop early, therefore the condition was never false
    output "the condition was always true!";
}
```

There are certainly ways to reorganize the above code to minimize the number of lines, but I wanted to keep it clear without introducing too many things at once.

Now, the disadvantage to that way is it's a bit more error prone. Notice that "final value" is used twice. This means if you *modify* your code by, say, modifying whatever the "final value" is, you have *two* lines to update instead of just one. This increases the possibility of accidentally forgetting to update one. Of course, if you stored "final value" in a variable you could eliminate this but I find the flag approach simpler all around. You always want to structure your code to minimize the possibility of mistakes.

There is a third possibility, which you may see sometimes, which is to check if you are at the end of the loop inside the loop itself (e.g. `if (n == final value - 1) { we made it through; }` inside the loop but after the `break`). I'm not going to give an example because I don't like this method. Philosophically, it has some deeper organizational issues, and also can have performance issues in certain situations. I'd go with the flag approach above.

Hopefully this is enough info for you to figure out how to solve the problem in your application.

Answer (score 0):

```
package asciitocvs;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class itr {
    public static void imageToNumRep(File input, File output)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(input);
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(output);
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            int count = 0;
            String text = in.nextLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
                if (i+1<text.length() && text.charAt(i) == text.charAt(i + 1)) {
                    count++;
                }else{
                    System.out.print(count + 1 + "," + text.charAt(i) + (i+1<text.length()?", ":""));
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
            out.print("\n");
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        imageToNumRep(new File("ascii.txt"), new File("/dev/stdout"));
    }
}
```

With a determine of i is or isn't the last char, Problem fixed.

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you could explain what the OP's initial problem was, why you made these changes and how they address the issue.

Comment: @JasonC Thank, I'm writting.